# Providing Search Option to Limit to questions placed by active users?

Tags: support, search

I was using some search options to filter unanswered questions, with zero answers to try and answer them, thus helping reducing the enormous unanswered questions count.

```
answers:0
closed:0
```

This effort will only be worth it if the user who placed the question actually gets to accept an answer (mine or not).

So I've tried to find a way to filter the questions whose users that placed them are still active, but after searching here on meta, and reading the [stackoverflow search options page](https://stackoverflow.com/search), I haven't found the proper way to do so. *(assuming such method does exist)*

Is it possible to apply a filter to questions, whose users that place them are still active?

Comment: I feel your pain, but I don't believe any means are available from the advanced search options alone.

Comment: You might be able to stir up some results on data.stackexchange.com, but I doubt this would get all of them

Comment: Same question is being asked at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/4234/115

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with the site search but for your particular use case a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query should be sufficient.

I have created [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/701446?active=2&tag=haskell) that let you enter a tag and for how many months the lastaccessdate of the OP may have passed.

```sql
-- active: Months user last active

select top 1000 
       p.id as [Post Link]
     , p.score
     , p.creationdate
     , datediff(mm, u.lastaccessdate,  getdate()) [User last seen]
from posts p
inner join users u on p.owneruserid = u.id
where p.posttypeid = 1
and p.answercount = 0
and p.closeddate is null
and datediff(mm, u.lastaccessdate,  getdate()) < ##active:int?2##
and p.tags like '%<'+ ##tag:string?haskell## + '>%'
order by p.creationdate desc
```

When run today for the Haskell tag on Stack Oveflow this will be your result:

[image: haskell unanswered questions]

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday.

If you like this and want to give creating queries a try yourself, checkout the [SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)